# Finite free objects

Tags: universal-algebra

Free distributive lattice with any number of generators is finite. For example with 3 generator the lattice will have 20 elements.

Is there other examples of free objects that are finite and have at least ten elements?

Comment: The free abelian-group-of-exponent-two on a finite number of generators is finite.

Comment: what do you mean by trivial here? As the question stands it highly unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: I changed the question a little. By "trivial" I meant something that obviously have only few elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example: any finitely generated free idempotent semigroup is finite.

Comment: So, if generators are a, b and c, then for example abcabc=(abc)(abc)=abc, and the free object will contain strings without those kind of copied parts. Thank you!

Comment: ...Or maybe not. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/the-longest-string-of-none-consecutive-repeated-pattern . It seems to say that for $n \ge 3$ the semigroup will be infinite.

Comment: The free idempotent semigroup satisfies $x^2 = x$ for each element $x$. And I confirm it is finite if it is finitely generated. See Green, J.A., Rees, D.: On semigroups in which $x^r = x$. *Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc.* **48**, 35–40 (1952)

Comment: I made a new question of this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371255/free-idempotent-semigroup-with-3-generators

Answer (score 1):

One notion you might be interested in is that of [locally finite varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_variety); they satisfy an apparently stronger finiteness requirement, namely: Every finitely generated algebra in it is finite. Indeed, this is equivalent to having all finitely generated *free* algebra finite.

A prominent example is the class of Boolean algebras.

There is a great deal of study of this varieties, in particular with the question of which of them are *decidable,* meaning that there is an effective procedure to determine if a first-order formula is a consequence of the axioms. The book **The structure of decidable locally finite varieties** by McKenzie and Valeriote has deep results in this direction. I suggest that you take a look into [its zbMATH review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0702.08001).

Answer (score 1):

One classical example, still unsolved in generality, is [Burnside groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem).

The free Burnside group $B(m,n)$ is defined to be the free group on $m$ generators with the relations $g^n=e$ for all $g\in B(m,n)$.

In general, it is unknown whether or not $B(m,n)$ is a finite group (though the answer is known in many cases).  In fact, we already do not know whether $B(2,5)$ is finite.