# Free idempotent semigroup with 3 generators

Tags: combinatorics, semigroups, universal-algebra

On [Finite free objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369730/finite-free-objects/1369770) I asked examples of finite free objects. I got answer "The free idempotent semigroup satisfies $x^2=x$ for each element $x$. And I confirm it is finite if it is finitely generated." with reference to a paper.

If I understood correctly the concept of free object, then elements of free idempotent semigroup of three generators can be seen as strings like "abaca" with "non-repeating" property: do not count for example "abcbc" because has "bc" repeats. Well, on [The longest string of none consecutive repeated pattern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/the-longest-string-of-none-consecutive-repeated-pattern) it is said that there is infinitely many strings of three letters with that property.

So either at least one of the answers is wrong, or then I have understood this wrong.

If given semigroup is finite, how many elements it has?

Comment: Non-repeating strings are not necessarily pairwise distinct in this monoid. For example, $abaaba$ can be simplified both to $\emptyset$ and to $aba$. Removing repeated substrings is not a confluent rewriting system.

Comment: I don't quite undestand... If I have a string like $aba$ and I add a letter, then I either will have new non-reducible string or not. In the example, if I add $a$, then not, if I add $c$ then yes.

Comment: Oops, I mistook $x^2 = x$ for $x^2 = 1$ at one point. But I suspect examples like this still exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are indeed infinite square-free words, but it does not prove that two distinct prefixes of an infinite square-free word cannot be equivalent under the congruence generated by the congruence $x = x^2$. Here you just considered the rewriting system $x^2 \to x$ and simply ignored the possibility $x \to x^2$.
For instance, you will find in [2] a detailed proof that $bacbcabc \sim bacabc$, although these two words are square-free.

As proved in [1], the number of elements of the free idempotent monoid on $n$ generators is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \prod_{i=1}^k\ (k-i+1)^{2^i}
$$
See [2, Chapter 2] for another proof. For $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$, one gets successively the values $1, 2, 7, 160, 332381$. This is [A005345](https://oeis.org/A005345) in the on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences.

[1] Green, J.A., Rees, D.: On semigroups in which $x^r=x$, *Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc.* **48**, 35–40 (1952)

[2] Lothaire, M., *Combinatorics on words*, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications **17**, (1983), Addison-Wesley Publishing Co., Reading, Mass.
New edition (1987), Cambridge University Press, ISBN 978-0-521-59924-5.

Comment: So, there must be a sequence of expands and shrinks between $bacbcabc$ and $bacabc$. I didn't invent what it is, but I'll try to code a program to find it. And if it don't work, I'll try to get the paper you refer to.

Comment: You can also play around with these things in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) as described [here](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/semigroups/doc/chap6_mj.html#X7BB29A6779E8066A.)

Comment: @james-mitchell, I got GAP working and it confirms the answer given above. But can it also show the shrink-expand -serie showing the equivalence of "bacbcabc" and "bacabc"?

Comment: This came up in discussion recently on Mastodon. Here's a [link](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100027341) for the first reference. Could anyone give a more precise reference for the Lothaire textbook? The [freely available version](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Auteurs/aaaDivers/Lothaire%20-%20Algebraic%20Combinatorics%20On%20Words.pdf) has "Sturmian Words" as the second chapter, which aren't relevant in any obvious way.

Comment: @morgan-rogers Your refer to another Lothaire's book, which is not the one I gave in the references. I can only confirm that the reference I gave is the correct one. Chapter 2 is entitled "Square-free words and idempotent semigroups" and is written by J. Berstel and C. Reutenauer.